# Is it possible for an Ember App that has nested ember apps inside?

Tags: ember.js

I am working on a project that needs to load separate widgets/apps at a later time than at the initial parent ember application kickoff. I want the separate apps to function as standalone ember application while also being able to loaded into the main application. Since I am unable to nest ember applications, I decided to use a subset of the ember functionality and eval the models, views, controllers, and templates when I request them. However these widgets (also functioning as a standalone ember app) have their own routes and data adapters that load controllers and associate them to views. What would be the best way to put the embedded routes into the main application's router and use a separate data adapter for them?

Alternatively if I don't use a separate data adapter and keep the widget to only using the ApplicationRoute to setup controllers can I have these widgets working correctly inside my ember app?

Has anyone attempted something similar?

Comment: Not sure, but this could help you: https://speakerdeck.com/christse/oasis-dot-js-sneak-peek